# issue with adding a method in object

Tags: javascript

I have this object:

```
var Point = {
    step: function () {
        alert("hello");
    }
};
```

This works:`Point.step();`.

How to make it work with the `[ ]` notation? Meaning `Point["property_name"]`.

Comment: `Point["step"]()`?

Comment: @ArunPJohny Can you please write your comment as an answer so you can take the credits for answering the question? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `Point["step"]();`. Here is the snippet:

```js
var Point = {
    step: function () {
        alert("hello");
    }
};

Point["step"]();
```

Comment: That's way too easy; moreover, already [pointed by Arun P Johny](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29386067/issue-with-adding-a-method-in-object#comment46950309_29386067).